# Google Search Console still reporting 5xx errors even when my server has been running flawlessly for 7 days

Tags: google-search-console, error, crawl-errors, http-code-500

For the past few days, I see that I have the following index coverage issue:

[image]

Last month I was working on my production server and during this time the production server threw some errors (this explains the 500 error).

But for the past 7 days, the server was working fine. I can browse to my home page and it is working, what I don't understand is I am still seeing error 500 on google search console?

### Update 1

This is what I see when I click on the error:

[image]

It is saying:

> Validation started: 6/1/2019

Does it mean that the error is potentially fixed, I jut have to wait till Google crawls the page again?

### Update 2

If I click on Valid pages, I can see the following... (my home page is not among the valid pages):

[image]

Then there is a list of excluded pages, which again does not contain the home page.

The home page appears on error page, I can click on it:

[image]

and this is what I get if I say inspect url:

[image]

I did request for reindexing, two days ago.

And if I click on: TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING, i get this message (I don't have any robots.txt in my root directory):

> **Property not in account**
>
> You are verified to see sc-domain://, but it's
>   not in your account.

### Update 3

This is how I have added my site to GSC:

[image]

- I have added the website domain
- I have added https with and without www as url prefix (I am not sure if adding the url prefixes are needed?)

Comment: If you click into the error, GSC should tell you when (what date) it encountered the error.  Just based on the graph, it looks like it found the error 5 days ago.   Maybe your server still threw an error in the last week?   5xx errors can be intermittent or dependent on variables such as user-agent.  Maybe it didn't work for Googlebot even if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, so this has nothing to do with the fact that the error is happening when google is requesting my website using http? since my website just redirects to https... would I be able to use GSC to get more info about the error? I cannot see any recent exception in my server log.

Comment: I have updated the question... it sounds like google is validation the error... what confuses me is that in the first screen shot, I see parallel red lines on the chart... do it mean that google has tried again is getting the same error? Or am I supposed to just wait for this to go away?

Comment: Is there more information below the graph?  A list of specific pages.  You should be able to click in further.

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, this was a matter of time and after 6 days, google cleared the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshots indicate you are looking at the http and non www version of your site.

The home page inspection report indicates that the home page for that site (http without www) is redirecting to the https with www version . https://www. and that it is not indexed because of that. That's from the "page with redirect" statement and what Google says it has selected as the canonical.

That makes me thing you are looking at the wrong site. If you always redirect to https://www then you should verify that site and look at its report.

You could have verified at the domain level, which means you are looking at all site variants. Which means it picking up the redirect is not an issue.

The report can have delays. I suspect the 500 is a red herring as when you click for details it says it redirects. I'd expect that status to change over time.

Redirects add an extra level to the procession (multiple URLs need to be crawled) which means it can take a bit longer for the true status to settle down. Make sure your https://www home page is indexed fine via the url inspection tool. If so, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have added *update 3* to show how I have added my website to GSC. The redirects are very simple, any http request would be redirected to https on the load balancer. I have selected `https www mysite com` as canonical. I have added `mysite com` as domain and I have added url prefixes: `https www mysite com` & `https www mysite com`. I have a feeling Google has not re-checked the website since it has started working, but since it has taken around 4 days since I asked Google to re-index the home page, and the error is still there, I am concerned maybe something else is wrong...

Comment: I am not sure why home page http without www is redirecting to https with www. Is this because https + www is canonical?

Comment: re your last suggestion, that I should make sure my https://www home page is indexed? How should I do this? I have already added this version to my sitemap and submitted to Google - is there anything else I need to do? (sorry so many questions)

Comment: http without www is redirecting because you said you are redirecting them all to https with www. So that url inspect report will not change, and is not an issue. You need to focus on the https with www URLs to make sure they get indexed as expected. Test https with www URLs in the url insepction tool to see if they are indexed and ok.